# Importing a file in meteor not working

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have the following directory structure :-

```
main_dir/
 packages/
  package1/
   admin/
    lib/
     router/
      router.js
   package2/
    client/
     sample.jsx
```

I simply want to import sample.jsx file inside router.js.
Any help for this query ?
Thanks.

Comment: try this: `import Sampe from '../../../../package2/client/sample.jsx'`.

Comment: check this: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export

Comment: Hi @MayankShukla  This doesn't work and gives me the error
`can not find module '../../../../package2/client/sample.jsx'`

Answer (score 0):

According to your directory structure any of the followings will work:

```
import {<Class1>, <Class2>, <Class3>} from '../../../../package2/client/sample.jsx'
```

or

```
import {<Class1>, <Class2>, <Class3>} from '/packages/package2/client/sample.jsx'
```

Make sure that you have exported the classes with `export` keyword in your `JSX` file.

Note: I'm assuming that your directory is like bellow:

```
main_dir/
| packages/
| | package1/
| | | admin/
| | | | lib/
| | | | | router/
| | | | | | router.js
| | package2/
| | | client/
| | | | sample.jsx
```

Comment: Hi, One thing, `package2/` is inside `packages/` directory not inside `package1/` directory. OK. Thanks.

Comment: Okay! updated my reply. In your question it looks like `package2` is inside `package1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sample from '../../../../package2/client/sample'
```

You should make the code exportable by using 'export' keyword inside sample.jsx file.

Comment: // Sample file should be like this..
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
class sample extends Component {
    //code
}
export default sample

Comment: and you should use export statement like "export default sample"